# OrientDB eCommerce use case + NodeJS

Tags: node.js, orientdb

I'm new on OrientDB, and I have this use case:

**Attributes(1,n)--->AttributesValues**

**Product(1,n)--->SKU<---(n,n)AttributesValues**

My question is: Can I get all SKUs (and AttributesValues, Attributes) from a Product with one query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TRAVERSE](https://orientdb.com/docs/last/SQL-Traverse.html) might be useful for this task. Unfortunately you don't specify how you want your data organised (the problem being TRAVERSE doesn't 'nest' records like you might be hoping for), so ultimately it might not be suitable, but it will definitely `get all SKUs (and AttributesValues, Attributes) from a Product with one query`.

*Note: I will make up some edge names below, as you didn't mention any.*

To get all the SKU of a product with rid #11:0, you could do something like `SELECT expand(out('has_SKU')) from #11:0`. To get all the attributes as well, you could do `TRAVERSE in('has_AttributeValue') FROM (SELECT expand(out('has_SKU')) from #11:0)`. You will now have a result set of all SKU and AttributesValues linked to the original product.

Unfortunately at this point, you don't really know which AttributesValue belongs to which SKU. Also, TRAVERSE only returns each record once, so if more than 1 SKU shares the same AttributesValue, it will only be in the results once. The SKU record will have an in_has_AttributeValue field though, which will be a list of AttributesValue rids, which you can use to associate the records in your software.

To get the Attributes as well, you could try something like `TRAVERSE in('has_AttributeValue','has_Attribute') FROM (SELECT expand(out('has_SKU')) from #11:0)`. This may or may not work depending on your how all your edges are setup. This traverse will follow any in_has_AttributeValue or in_has_Attribute field on each record it finds. If an SKU has some Attributes directly linked to it, but you only want attributes linked to an AttributeValue, and these use the same edge name (ie has_Attribute), then this query wouldn't be suitable. You should consider such a scenario, and design your database setup appropriately (namely by using specific edge names).